# Is it possible to make functional tests use my `bitcoind` running node as node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, regtest, functional-test

I'm trying to fix some tests that are broken due to my own changes in the code base, and need to simultaneously run functional tests and `bitconid` in `regtest` mode and make functional tests to use my `bitcoind` running as `self.nodes[0]`. Is this possible? I'm very new to python tests and have almost zero experience with regard to them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Testing running `bitcoind` instances is exactly what the functional test framework is for.

Comment: @PieterWuille You're right. I failed to explain what I need accurately. I want to run `bitcoind` in debug mode using `gdb` and simultaneously running functional tests. I want functional tests to catch my breakpoints in the `bitcoind`.